# Excel index match formula with large if paramaters

Tags: excel

Im wondering if someone can help insert an OR option into the below formula

```
=INDEX(B2:B211,MATCH(LARGE(IF(C2:C211=HomeTeam,B2:B211,""),1),B2:B211,0))
```

Ive tried the below but unfortunately this brings back an incorrect result

```
=INDEX(B2:B211,MATCH(LARGE(IF(OR(C2:C211=HomeTeam,D2:D211=HomeTeam),B2:B211,""),1),B2:B211,0))
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is to use + rather than OR - the OR function returns a single value not an array as required here, so it doesn't work as expected in array formulas

Try like this

`=INDEX(B2:B211,MATCH(LARGE(IF((C2:C211=HomeTeam)+(D2:D211=HomeTeam),B2:B211),1),B2:B211,0))`

I'm assuming that HomeTeam is a named range (hence no quotes) - is that a single value?

As you are returning the value itself here you don't really need INDEX and MATCH in any case, you can use just

`=LARGE(IF((C2:C211=HomeTeam)+(D2:D211=HomeTeam),B2:B211),1)`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and you suggestion - Hometeam is a named ranged and a single value so Ive used  =LARGE(IF((C2:C211=HomeTeam)+(D2:D211=HomeTeam),B2:B211),1)